# 1120 error by adding a var in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, air

On the adobe website was this code:

`var conn:SQLConnection = new SQLConnection(); 
var dbFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("DBSample.db");`

try 
{ 
    conn.open(dbFile); 
    trace("the database was created successfully"); 
} 
catch (error:SQLError) 
{ 
    trace("Error message:", error.message); 
    trace("Details:", error.details); 
}

on the line of

`conn.open(dbFile);`

there is an errorcode: 1120, Access of undefined property

Can anyone help? I just started with flex.

@aftee:
Here is the whole mx:Script, it stays also between CDATA

import flash.data.SQLConnection;
import flash.data.SQLStatement;
import flash.events.SQLErrorEvent;
import flash.events.SQLEvent;
import flash.errors.SQLError;
import flash.filesystem.File;

var conn:SQLConnection = new SQLConnection(); 
var dbFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("DBSample.db");

try 
{ 
    conn.open(dbFile); 
    trace("the database was created successfully"); 
} 
catch (error:SQLError) 
{ 
    trace("Error message:", error.message); 
    trace("Details:", error.details); 
}
var createStmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement(); 
createStmt.sqlConnection = conn; 
var sql:String =
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees (" +
    "    empId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
    "    firstName TEXT, " +
    "    lastName TEXT, " +
    "    salary NUMERIC CHECK (salary > 0)" +
    ")"; 
createStmt.text = sql; 
createStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, createResult); 
createStmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, createError); 
createStmt.execute(); 
function createResult(event:SQLEvent):void 
{ 
    trace("Table created"); 
} 
function createError(event:SQLErrorEvent):void 
{ 
    trace("Error message:", event.error.message); 
    trace("Details:", event.error.details); 
}

Comment: can you paste all application code?!

Comment: or give a link to that adobe tutorial

Comment: do you develop in Flex Builder or Flash professional ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to the mx:application tag this option: `creationComplete="init()"`

and put your code to this function

```
private function init():void {
var conn:SQLConnection = new SQLConnection(); 
var dbFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("DBSample.db");

conn.open(dbFile);
...
}
```